# Adding a dependency to Android project

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I am trying to set up the `slidingmenu` library by jfeinstein into a project.  One of his instructions calls for:

`Add ActionBarSherlock as a dependency to SlidingMenu`

I already have ActionBatSherlock integrated into the app I am doing, so it is setup in Eclipse.  But how do I add it as a dependency?  I thought (and tried) to add ActionBarSherlock as a Library of Sliding Menu but that broke the Sliding Menu library in multiple places.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]Right-click on the SlidingMenu project.

Click on Properties (bottom selection of the sub-menu).

Then in the window (Properties editor), you will select: Android

In the bottom right, click the "Add..." Button, and follow flow to select, and add the library.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it broke the SlidingMenu project... but if that is all a dependency means, then I have more to figure out.. thanks again for confirming that.

Comment: If you have ABS and SlidingMenu both as dependancies in your main project, I didn't do this step (making this link).  My project works fine (I guess the libraries are all linked by my project).  Good luck.

Comment: Turned out it was an issue with API level as well as the support library. All good now.